# In Unity I can't figure out what to put as a parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {}
```

```
private void Update()
{
    OnCollisionEnter("Here"); <----
}
```

Comment: An instance of the class `Collision` and not a `string`. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html

Comment: this method is called by the engine, you don't need to call it in update. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: Not enough information to give a solid answer, but the method expects a Collision Object. Have you taken a look at the documentation of the object 'Collision'?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html

Comment: Rand Random the string is there to point where i had the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnCollisionEnter` is an event *callback* and is **not** supposed to be called as you have done.

Unity automatically calls it when the object (which is a `RigidBody`) collides with another object with a `collider`. For example, consider a `Player` object colliding with the `Enemy` object

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Enemy")
        {
           //Destroy Player
        }
    }
}
```